# Get non zero values including null

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table with column having value 0, null and 1. I need record having non 0 values, including null and 1. I need to query using eloquent.

My table looks like this:

```
id | user_id | medical | gsg  |interview_result | flight | created_at
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 |   1     | null    | null |      1          | null   | anydate
 2 |   2     |   0     | null |      1          | null   | anydate
 3 |   3     |   1     |   1  |      1          |   1    | anydate
 4 |   8     |   1     |   1  |      1          |   0    | anydate
```

Please answer this question. I want non 0 values including null. Mysql + Eloquent. Great if you give eloquent code.

Note: gsg, medical, interview_result should be non 0 including null. Other column needn't be used.

Comment: Is this SQL or an HTML table?

Comment: just sql data represented in table, for reference.

Comment: Why not just do an ASCII table?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [where clause](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses) to match rows that not include 0, here is an example:

```
DB::table('table')
    ->where('gsg', '<>', 0)
    ->where('medical', '<>', 0)
    ->where('interview_result', '<>', 0)
    ->get();
```

Hope this helps